# How to disable sleep in MacOS while processing program is running?

Tags: processing

I created a digital full screen Clock in Processing. I also created a executable file to run it directly via double click. My OS is MacOS High Sierra. When I run it, my laptop goes to sleep after some time. I want to disable sleeping while my clock is running. Is there a programming way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [Amphetamine](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12&at=1010loXs&ct=227561) to do this. It's not programmatic though, which might not be possible from Processing (unless you can do Objective C style calls).

Comment: I want it to be automatic. Something like when we play video, it does not sleep. Like this when I start my clock it should not go to sleep.